# Installing feynarts diag

Tags: packages, mathlink-or-wstp, installation

I'm trying to install this package: http://www.feynarts.de/diag/, I followed the instruction entering

```
./configure
make
make install
```

but when I type `Install["Diag"]` in *Mathematica* I got the error:

> LinkOpen::linke: Could not find MathLink executable. >>.

What's the problem?

Comment: Greetings! To make the most of Mma.SE please **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimum** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: This forum might certainly include users of `feynarts`, but for more expedient access to installation / configuration for a specific add-on package, you may be better off contacting the developer of that package directly.